# Odd blue line when reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a script that automatically shows a video on fullscreen, and it's all working perfectly,but for some reason, when I load a page, it gets this odd blue line on the side of my screen, which is gone on clicking somewhere on the page. Does anyone know why this happens?

[Maybe not clearly visible, second one should be more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhinL.png)

[Made a second screenshot where partially is offscreen so you can see it clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFuaH.png)

Comment: This might be `border:;`

Comment: Could you add the code that isn't working as expected?

Comment: It's probably the focus highlight. Make sure to take the focus away once the user clicks on the UI or use css to hide the focus highlight.

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit more on what I'm working on, I'm making an autoplay function for kissanime.com that automatically puts the video in fullscreen, and when the video ends it goes to the next episode. Everything is working as intended, it's just the blue line that is very odd.
[Code](https://gist.github.com/SubSide/b988b0056a4478cb949d).
I'm making the script with tampermonkey, an extension that gives me the ability to add my own javascript to specific websites.The blue lines are gone on page clicking, or selecting other text, but checking with console, nothing is selected.

Comment: thanksd as mentioned above, everything is working as expected, it's just a weird blue line (which can be caused by the website itself, but I doubt that). TechnicCoder2000 I tried that already, without result. @Achshar Nothing is selected if I check the selected area with javascript. Forcing a different selection with javascript doesn't work either. Also worth mentioning is that adding a padding of 1 removes it, but adding a margin of -1 (to place it back) makes it return again.

Comment: What happens when you press tab when the line is showing? If nothing else works I always keep reducing the code until he problem is fixed, which usually gives clues.

Comment: @Achshar pressing tab did actually remove it

Comment: @ThomasvandenBulk So it's the focus then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably the focus "glow". It's called the outline of an element. Any element with a tab index will have the focus outline. You can remove it with css easily.

```
video {
    outline: none;
}
```

That should be enough.